# Convert Integer to int in Java as a return type of stack

Tags: java, integer, int

In some code, I have to push some numbers in a stack and print them later. So I have tried this:

```
package bf;

import java.util.Stack;

public class BF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = null ;
        stack.push(1);
        int a = Integer.parseInt("" + stack.pop());
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Each time I try to do this, I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bf.BF.main(BF.java:12)
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

My questions:

1. Is there any way to convert `Integer` to `int`? How?
2. I must use a stack. Later I need to pop and save it to an `int` variable, so what else I can do? Is there not any way (I have to create a stack myself)?

*There were some questions with the same/nearly the same title in Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find an answer that worked in my case.*

Comment: An `Integer` is basically an `int`, and in most cases (e.g. the ones you are encountering) you can use them interchangeably. Look up autoboxing.

Comment: you need to initialize your `stack` before use it (`stack = new Stack<>();`)...

Comment: @Jashaszun
int a = Integer.parseInt(""+stack.pop());
can you correct this line for saving to int purpose please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of problems:

First, as Alex stated above, you need to initialize your stack before you use it. If it's null, then how could you expect to add anything to it?

Second, as I stated above, you can basically use `Integer` as interchangeable with `int` when boxing/unboxing due to autoboxing in Java.

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>(); // initialize first
stack.push(1);
int a = stack.pop(); // just pop, no need to convert to string and parse
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, it is called **auto-unboxing**, which is the process that will automatically convert a wrapper class (here `Integer`) to its corresponding primitive type (here `int`) so actually you have nothing to do.

Here is the correct code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(1);
    int a = stack.pop();
}
```

**NB:** The opposite also exists, it is called **auto-boxing** which is the process that will automatically convert a primitive type to its corresponding wrapper class